# Problems with docker api and web app containers

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating a solution with asp.net core that contains a webapp and an api. Both projects were configured to run in a docker container. There is a 3rd container, which is the database container. I'm using MySQL.
I created docker-compose ps and apparently everything looks fine, but I can't access the API in the browser. Only the web app is accessed by the browser.
[image]

[image]

[image]

My connection string
[image]

Meu Dockerfile API

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
LABEL version="1.0.0" description="API Produto"
COPY dist /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80/tcp
EXPOSE 445
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "APIProduto.dll", "--environment=Development"]
```

Meu Dockerfile WebApp

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
LABEL version="1.0.0" description="Web App Produto"
COPY dist /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80/tcp
EXPOSE 444
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebAppProduto.dll", "--environment=Development"]
```

Meu docker-compose

```
version: "3"

volumes:
    produtosdata:
    
networks:
    frontend:
    backend:
    dbhost:
    
services:
        mysql:
            image: "mysql:5.7"
            volumes:
             - produtosdata:/var/lib/mysql
             - ./MySql_Init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            networks:
             - dbhost
            environment:
             - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=senhaprodutos1257
             - bind-address=0.0.0.0
             
        apiproduto:
            build:
                context: ./APIProduto
                dockerfile: Dockerfile
            networks:
                - dbhost
                - backend
            ports:
                - 5002:80
            environment:
                - DBHOST=mysql
            depends_on:
                - mysql
                
        webappproduto:
            build:
                context: ./WebAppProduto
                dockerfile: Dockerfile
            networks:
                - backend
                - frontend
            ports:
                - 5001:80
            environment:
                - HOST=apiproduto
            depends_on:
                - apiproduto
```

Can anyone help me to find out what could be wrong?

Comment: I want to know how your api looks like ? API end point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you how to find solution.

1. First of all you are getting 404 error so you are hitting container but default endpoint is not at localhost:5002.
2. Let's for example if you are accessing your api like http://localhost:5002/api/values or http://localhost:5002/weatherforcast so try that.